# checkbox inside of span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have a checkbox inside the span. Everything is working fine with a span when I click on it ,it basically outputs the total , but now I want to have a checkbox inside the span and I don't know how to put it in this particular situation...Could someone point me in the right direction ? Thanks in advance!

this is what I have right now

```
var amount_field = $("#Amount");

var req_link = $("<span/>", {
    "class": "action_link",
});
req_link.text("Required Payment");
req_link.click(function() {
    amount_field.val('this is where the total is outputted ');
});
```

how do I include this checkox in my span ? Or there is a different way to do this ?

```
var checkbox_field = $("<input/>", {            
    "type": "checkbox",
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) it into the span object your creating:

```
var req_link = $("<span/>", {
    "class": "action_link",
});

var checkbox_field = $("<input/>", {            
    "type": "checkbox",
});

req_link.append(checkbox_field);
```